# Killing service fabric instance when stopping debug session

Tags: visual-studio, azure-service-fabric

I have noticed that when I start a service fabric project on my machine from visual studio the instance keeps running after I stop the debug session.

Can I change it so that the instance is terminated when I stop the debug sessoion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your VS project, change the Application Debug Mode setting to 'Remove Application'.
More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-application-in-visual-studio#deploy-your-service-fabric-application).